# What sets the $SHELL environment variable?

Tags: shell, environment-variables, defaults

Where is the environment variable `$SHELL` first set on a UNIX system?

How can I find and print all of this type of default settings of my terminal?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Traditionally, by [login(1)](http://man.openbsd.org/?query=login&sec=1):

```
ENVIRONMENT
     login sets the following environment variables:

     HOME        The user's home directory, as specified by the password
                 database.

     SHELL       The user's shell, as specified by the password database.
```

Though these days it might be a window manager or terminal program making those settings, depending on the flavor of unix and how far they've departed from tradition. `env` will show what's currently set in the environment, which a shell or something else may have altered from the default. However, "terminal settings" are not typically environment variables, and shells like `bash` or `zsh` have a `set` command, and other places they hide settings...

Comment: Any idea what sets SHELL when logging in via SSH? Is login(1) involved (maybe via PAM)?

Comment: @dpat, I reckon it's worth asking the OP whether they want to clarify whether their question is merely for local systems, and if so, ask your own about SSH. Otherwise, respondents here might neglect to consider SSH.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the default values of your system in `/etc/default/useradd` or with `sudo useradd -D`, this will output the default value for `$SHELL` and other variables.