# SHELL environment variable still points to zsh after using bash

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I am trying to jump between zsh and bash.

By default, I have zsh as my shell, I can know this by typing:

`echo $SHELL` and I get `/bin/zsh`

However, I want to open Bash, so I type `/bin/bash`; I assume I am in bash now, but if I echo `$SHELL` I still get `/bin/zsh`

What's wrong, please?

Comment: Linking in for similarity: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/71121/117549

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SHELL is an environment variable that is passed from bash to zsh when you call zsh. SHELL is not one of the [Parameters Set By The Shell](https://linux.die.net/man/1/zshparam) in zsh, so its value remains intact.

```
bash$ SHELL=turtle zsh
zsh$ echo $SHELL
turtle
```

For indications that you're in a zsh shell, try:

```
echo $ZSH_NAME
echo $0
```

The `SHELL` variable is traditionally set by the `login` program, "as specified by the password database". (Copied from [What sets the $SHELL environment variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277944/what-sets-the-shell-environment-variable))

Comment: I'd welcome better indications of a zsh shell; a possible list includes $module_path and $ZSH_VERSION, although in theory other shells could set those.

Comment: Also for consideration: `ps -ocomm= -p $$`

Comment: thank you, but how did $SHELL get assigned in the first place? I install zsh just recently

Comment: Great point, @Jack. See the update; your passwd entry likely still points to /bin/bash; you may try (or request the change) to set it to zsh.

Answer (score 2):

Many shells set a version variable on starting.

`bash` use BASH_VERSION and `zsh` use ZSH_VERSION.

Setting both variables to a known value will reliably detect which shell was started:

```
BASH_VERSION=notbash ZSH_VERSION=notzsh sh -c 'echo "$BASH_VERSION $ZSH_VERSION"'
```

will print `notbash 5.3.1` if sh is zsh or `5.0.2(2)-release notzsh` if sh is bash.

Sadly ksh segfaults on using KSH_VERSION with a string value.

Comment: maybe echo $0 is a bit easier than ZSH_VERSION, BASH_VERSION. but I like the idea, didn't about those variables

Comment: The value of $0 could be modified at will, for example: `sh -c 'echo "$0"' MyNameOfShell` and by several other methods. @JackThomson

Comment: fair point, indeed