# when i chsh to zsh it seems to get replaced with fish (garuda)

Tags: shell, arch-linux

I ran a fresh install of garuda dragonised,it comes with a fish shell by default. I had no experience with this so asked the installer to add zsh -which it did along with config files.

Upon booting into the system I was still running fish but zsh appeared to be installed and have config in place so I tried chsh and a reboot on my login account.

Upon logging back in `echo "$SHELL"` will return `/usr/bin/zsh` but the active shell is very clearly still fish

To be honest I kinda gave up and decided to roll with fish yesterday but I would like to try to understand what might have happened...

I was very clear not to get confused between my own account and sudo - in fact I set both to zsh and rebooted again for good measure with no change to the actual shell presented (still fish) for either but with both reporting /usr/zsh or /usr/bin/zsh

if i try to run `source ~/.zshrc` then I get errors about assignment using = in fish, I should use SET HISTFILE instead

UPDATE: changed title to reflect new understanding, I have also removed zsh, all config and re-installed

- I can run zsh manually and it seems to work fine
- i am launching the shell from konsole via the gui

I am now thinking the call to launch konsole is probably binding a particular shell - any tips where to look would be appreciated

Comment: what does `which /bin/sh` return

Comment: Related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/522907/shell-environment-variable-still-points-to-zsh-after-using-bash?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @belkarx `ẁhich /bin/sh` returns /bin/sh

Comment: @fuzzydrawings thanks, I'll have a read

Comment: @fuzzydrawings - im still reading that link but the accepted answer seems not applicable- if this was just an incorrect $SHELL variable then the zshrc would have parsed properly wouldn't it? or am i misunderstanding something

Comment: How did you use `chsh`? If you used it with `sudo`, you've changed root's login shell, not yours. Do you have a `.zshrc`, `.zprofile` or `.zshenv` file in your home directory? If so, does it say to start  the `fish` shell? Can you start the `zsh` shell by typing `zsh`?

Comment: @they no, I changed both for good measure - I saw another question where that was the issue so was very careful

Comment: What does `getent passwd yourusername` print?

Comment: See also [Why would echo $shell come up with a blank output?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/667271) and [Switching to another shell without copying environment variables](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/67603)

Comment: @they yesterday I had .zshrc, and a .zhistory (that wasnt getting populated generally but had some entries from where i had explicitly launched zsh at some point) and maybe something else in my home, they were all set up by garuda. Since then I haveI deleted all those files and removed zsh completely. I have resinstalled and switched again to test. I now have the same situation with just a .zshrc file copied from /etc/skel. the output of getent passwd is: dan:x:1000:1000:dan:/home/dan:/usr/bin/zsh but i am still clearly in fish and i get same fish error parsing .zshrc

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas It is definitely not just an issue with the SHELL variable being incorrect because my fish configuration is working great whilst everything tells me I am using zsh - I am 100% using fish when I dont expect to be (honestly fish is great and I probably will stick with it I just want to know what is happening)

Comment: @they yes I seem to be able to start a zsh explicitly its just giving me fish by default and telling me its using zsh

Comment: something must be switch the shell to fish after it has been set to zsh (and not updating the SHELL variable when it does)... but i dont know what

Comment: `$SHELL` is the variable that determines your prefered shell. Applications such as xterm or vi that start or may start a shell for you will use that. That's all there is to that variable. It is set by `login` or other login managers to your *login shell* as defined in the `passwd` database. If `fish` is started in whatever terminal you're using, you need to determine how. In what context are we here. Is that in a terminal emulator, is that over ssh?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas im just updating the question to summarise - but I am launching the shell using the Konsole terminal and was just wondering if that is where the issue is, perhaps konsole is launching with a reference to the fish shell... that would make sense if konsole is ignoring my shell settings and leaving the $SHELL var as it is

Comment: What's the value of the `SHELL` environment variable that `konsole` itself returned on startup? What's the output (from a zsh shell) of `grep -z '^SHELL=' /proc/${^$(pidof konsole)}/environ | tr '\0' '\n'`?

Comment: How was `konsole` started? What's the output of `ps -wo args -C konsole`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas thanks for help - you were correct, i found a setting through the gui to bind a shell for konsole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all for your help in working through this.

It turned out to be a setting binding the shell to the Konsole terminal. There is a command line flag to pass this in when launching.

For the garuda KDE based desktop you can access this setting under `settings->configure konsole-> edit profile` from the konsole gui menus`

Answer (score 0):

Right clicking in the fish terminal then under configure profile under command changing it to /usr/bin/zsh solve my problem.
It was stuck with /usr/bin/fish