# Docker does not trigger login or invoke /etc/profiles?

Tags: bash, docker, configuration, environment-variables, login

Trying to deal with the problem of

`dircolors: no SHELL environment variable, and no shell type option given`

when I start my docker container.

So from
[What sets the $SHELL environment variable?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277944/what-sets-the-shell-environment-variable) it can be infered that [login(1)](http://man.openbsd.org/?query=login&sec=1) is not triggered,

And I've put a `env.sh` in  `/etc/profile.d`:

```bash
$ cat /etc/profile.d/env.sh 
SHELL=/bin/sh

$ ls -l /etc/profile.d/env.sh 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 14 Feb 24 18:21 /etc/profile.d/env.sh
```

and apparently that is not invoked either, as when I'm within my docker container, all that I have is:

```bash
$ env | grep SH
SHLVL=0
```

How to solve the SHELL environment variable definition problem?

Comment: So, did you find out?

Comment: IIRC, define (hard-code) and export it in `~/.bashrc` @Matthieu. LMK if there are better options.

Comment: thanks. I did the same but in `/etc/bash.bashrc`. I couldn't (quickly) find anything for `sh`; only for `bash`